# InfluxDB keeps appending to /var/log/syslog

Tags: logging, influxdb, syslog

**Problem**

I am running influxDB version: 1.7.8 on Ubuntu machine (18.04.3 LTS).
Currently the `/var/log/syslog` file is growing at very high rate (about 5-10BG per 24h).
I looked into what is being appending and it looks like this:

```
my_server:/var/log$ sudo tail /var/log/syslog
Feb 17 19:24:28 my_server_name influxd[12946]: [httpd] 127.0.0.1 - root [17/Feb/2020:19:24:28 +0000] "POST /write?db=db_name HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "-" "python-requests/2.21.0" 1dd1516f-51bb-11ea-98f7-3a83c7c53dec 1192
Feb 17 19:24:28 my_server_name influxd[12946]: [httpd] 127.0.0.1 - root [17/Feb/2020:19:24:28 +0000] "POST /write?db=db_name HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "-" "python-requests/2.21.0" 1dd1d454-51bb-11ea-98f8-3a83c7c53dec 1092
Feb 17 19:24:28 my_server_name influxd[12946]: [httpd] 127.0.0.1 - root [17/Feb/2020:19:24:28 +0000] "POST /write?db=db_name HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "-" "python-requests/2.21.0" 1dd20d47-51bb-11ea-98f9-3a83c7c53dec 1077
```

I recognize the `python-requests` as it's downloading data via API.

**Attempted solution**

I read [here](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/8319) and [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/administration/config#logging-settings) that the default logging level of InfluxDB is `info`, so changing to `error` should fix the issue.

I changed it to `error` and then reloaded the service by:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart influxdb.service
```

However the syslog keeps increasing every second...

Can anyone help me get to the bottom of this?

**Update 1**

I wonder whether it has something to do with the HTTP logs in the documentation [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/administration/config#log-enabled-true)? But I don't see any log level there.
Ideally I'd like warning and error to be logged (ofc).

**Update 2**

In `/etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf` under `[http]` I also tried changing `log-enabled = false` and `suppress-write-log = true`, but the writing to the `syslog` does not stop...

Answer (score 3):

in `[http]` section

```
flux-log-enabled = false
suppress-write-log = true
access-log-status-filters = ["5xx", "4xx"]
```

this will only print request which has error code in `5xx` and `4xx`

Comment: sadly, it keeps printing everything :(